# Active Directory Nested group members enumeration in c#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am developing a c# program. Consider users should be a member of group A in Active Directory to have permission to access a part of my application.
Also group B is a member of group A so, users of group B should have the same access.
Now Consider group A contains many groups so how should I know user X has permission.
Is the only way to check recursively?

Comment: Assuming you're using LDAP to query AD: do a base search for the user in question and [fetch their `tokenGroups`](https://morgantechspace.com/2015/08/active-directory-tokengroups-vs-memberof.html) on login - it'll contain a flattened list of security groups the user is a member of

Comment: Is this a web application or desktop application? You may already have that information without having to make an LDAP call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer in MSDN: [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupprincipal.getmembers?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

```
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,                                                                      
                                            "fabrikam.com",   
                                            "DC=fabrikam,DC=com",   
                                            "administrator",   
                                            "SecretPwd123");  

GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx,   
                                                   IdentityType.Name,   
                                                   "Domain Admins");  

if (grp != null)  
{  
    foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(true))  
    {  
         Console.WriteLine(p.Name);  
    }  
    grp.Dispose();  
}  

ctx.Dispose();
```

The point was "GetMembers(true)"